# Realgud to default to my most recent python executable

Tags: debugging, elpy, realgud

When I run realgud for python debugging, with:

`M-x realgud:pdb`

I see this prompt:

```
Run pdb (like this): python -m pdb /home/username/work/place/scratch.py
```

I'm using a conda environment installed in `./place/environments/default/`, so I'd like to use the python executable at `./place/environments/default/bin/python`

This means I have to type out a correction to use a different python:`

```
Run pdb (like this): /home/username/work/place/environments/default/bin/python -m pdb /home/username/work/place/scratch.py
```

installed in that directory every time I invoke pdb, which is tedious.

I have multiple projects in

```
/home/username/work/
```

So I can't just hard-code /one/, it needs to be configurable---but I'd like something like the following:

1. Default to using the last python binary I used but otherwise make me type this once.
2. Multi-step dialog, where the first step chooses a python (and defaults to last time).
3. Some variable I can set once per project and get picked up
4. Being able to tab complete here.

What options do I have to reduce the amount I have to type to change the python invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realgud:ipdb has a variable that indicate the command-name, is called `realdu:pdb-command-name` by default is set to "python -m pdb", but it can easily be adapted to use with differents projects (I'm assuming that you are using [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile), if it's not the case, take a look at [project.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/project.el))

We can assume that the location of the python executable has some similarities between projects (it's in the environment directory in the root project) if it's not the case, [Directory-Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) may help you, as you can define this variable in every directory regardless of the project.

So, for the first case, we can use a `python-mode-hook` and add some logic:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (let* ((conda-python (format "%/environments/default/bin/python -m pdb" (projectile-project-root))))
      (setq-local realgud:pdb-command-name conda-python))
    ))
```

This hook will ensure that for every file in a project, it will set a different variable, making possible to work with differents projects at the same time, mostly because we are using a buffer-local variable.

When realgud:pdb is launch, it will put the correct projectile base root, and will concat the file name at the end, making the file selection automatic.

For the 2 and 4 request, it is not implemented, but it can be an interesting addition to the realgud project, I really suggest you to contribute it (or open an issue) to the [realgud project](https://github.com/realgud/realgud).

Good luck!

Comment: This is amazing, thank you!

Comment: Hmm, this seems to disable my magit, oddly.  When I include this n my .dir-locals.el, I get `wrong type argument: listp, add-hook`

Comment: I am combining both of your excellent suggestions poorly and having a bit of trouble, I'll post a new question :)