# realgud pdb with .dir-locals.el

Tags: directory-local-variables, realgud

I'm trying to use directory local variables so my `realgud:pdb` invocation can be:

```
Run pdb (like this): /home/username/work/place/environments/default/bin/python -m pdb /home/username/work/place/scratch.py
```

Instead of :

```
Run pdb (like this): python -m pdb /home/username/work/place/scratch.py
```

as suggested [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61543/realgud-to-default-to-my-most-recent-python-executable).

However, in order to transform the suggestion there to be compatible with `.dir-locals.el`, I understand I need to use nil and eval [per this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26097/15646).

So I am left with this:

```
;; .dir-locals.el
;; set the test runner
((nil . ((eval . (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (function (lambda ()
              (let* ((conda-python (format "%/envs/default/bin/python -m pdb" (projectile-project-root))))
                (setq-local realgud:pdb-command-name conda-python))
              )))
         ))
      ))
```

This doesn't complain or fail, except for asking me whether I trust the eval parameters.  However, it doesn't seem to work, as my `M-x realgud:pdb` invocation is still:

```
Run pdb (like this): python -m pdb /home/username/work/place/scratch.py
```

My `init.el` contains:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(conda-anaconda-home (expand-file-name "~/anaconda3"))
 '(elpy-test-pytest-runner-command '("py.test"))
 '(elpy-test-runner 'elpy-test-pytest-runner)
```

...which I don't think interferes but include for completeness.

What should I change so that my `.dir-local.el` picks up the correct test runner for pdb?  Essentially, I am trying to combine the suggestion of the linked answer to modify my `init.el`, but in a per directory basis, using `.dir-locals.el`, as my projects have different environment names and I'm stuck having one per project.

Comment: For instance, this currently gives me:
```let*: Invalid format operation %/```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried instead of setting a hook, just eval the variable with the `python-mode` association  and seems to work fine, here is the code:

```
((python-mode . ((eval .
           (setq-local realgud:pdb-command-name (concat
                             (projectile-project-root)
                             "envs/default/bin/python -m pdb"))))))
```